# Генерация ключей

Tags: ubuntu, безопасность, gpg

Мне требуется сгенерировать `gpg-key`, но, прождав довольно много времени после появления сообщения:

> We need to generate a lot of random bytes. It is a good idea to
> perform some other action (type on the keyboard, move the mouse,
> utilize the disks) during the prime generation; this gives the random
> number generator a better chance to gain enough entropy.

я так и не получил результат. Случайные данные я пробовал вводить.

Команда для исполнения:

```
gpg --generate-key
```

Comment: На виртуалке?) там нужны хаки чтоб разогнать энтропию...

Comment: @eri ша напишу ответ

Comment: Решил...........

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/471412/gpg-gen-key-hangs-at-gaining-enough-entropy-on-centos-6 вот ещё куча ответов. Ссылочка для ищущих в будующем

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Судя по всему проблема в генераторе случайных чисел. Решение я нашёл [здесь](https://serverfault.com/questions/214605/gpg-does-not-have-enough-entropy) и [здесь](https://linux-audit.com/gpg-key-generation-not-enough-random-bytes-available/).

**Fedora/Rh/Centos**:

```
sudo yum install rng-tools
```

**Ubuntu/Debian**:

```
sudo apt-get install rng-tools
```

Затем запустите

```
sudo rngd -r /dev/urandom
```

Теперь можно сгенерировать ключи.

```
gpg --generate-key
```

Затем, после ввода персональной информации, Вы, вероятно, получите дважды следующее сообщение:

```
We need to generate a lot of random bytes. It is a good idea to perform
some other action (type on the keyboard, move the mouse, utilize the
disks) during the prime generation; this gives the random number
generator a better chance to gain enough entropy.
```

Затем, что-то в духе:

```
gpg: /home/username/.gnupg/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created
gpg: key 0B8634BGA76380DA marked as ultimately trusted
gpg: directory '/home/username/.gnupg/openpgp-revocs.d' created
gpg: revocation certificate stored as '/home/username/.gnupg/openpgp-revocs.d/620C6DE274C68UJ2DCFC6BF60B870XSFAA7EC80DA.rev'
public and secret key created and signed.

pub   rsa3072 2020-09-24 [SC] [expires: 2022-09-24]
      620C6DE274C68UJ2DCFC6BF60B870XSFAA7EC80DA
uid                      First Last <Email@Domain.ru>
sub   rsa3072 2020-09-24 [E] [expires: 2022-09-24]
```

Наконец, в Вашей директории будет эта папка `.gnupg/`:

```
openpgp-revocs.d/
private-keys-v1.d/
pubring.kbx
pubring.kbx~
trustdb.gpg
```